# Getting index in For Loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi if i want to know when i reached the last iteration of my

```
for c in text:
```

In C it will seem like :

```
for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)

   if (i == strlen(str))
     printf("The last index");
```

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to test whether a loop finished completely (i.e. exhausted its iterable) is to use [`for` with `else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
s = 'Hello World!'
for c in s:
    # do something with character c, your code might break the loop
    pass
else:
     # the loop did not break, and iterated over all characters
     print('The loop finished!')
```

Comment: I cant use my "for c in text" and then playing with the c like a pointer in C ?

Comment: You want to iterate over the characters in a string? You can directly iterate over the characters of a string without having to dereference the 'pointer', by just iterating over it.

Comment: use of `for` and `else` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to create a counter outside the loop and increment it every time the loop iterates so you can have a reference of what the loop index is.

Check out the Python built-in function "enumerate", here is a link: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate statement. It is written like this:

```
for index, val in enumerate(N):
   if index + 1 == len(N):
       print('The last index')
```

Comment: But i want to save my char iteration in my string

Answer (score 0):

If you want see in console the state of your loop, you can use `tqdm`,

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(N)):
     #Some logic here
```